# segFaut by allocating memory for pointer to pointer in struct

Tags: c

I have a pointer to char pointer in a struct. so there is a struct poiter object that I will pass to thread but thats not relevant.

so this is my struct

```
struct shard
{
    sem_t *semaphore_o;
    char **input;
    char **image_o;
};
```

I am creating object like

```
struct shard *obj=malloc(sizeof(struct shard));
```

and I am allocating the input in shard struct

```
*(obj->input)=malloc(sizeof(char)+1);
```

but abocve line giving segFault

Comment: what I am trying with input is if I do `printf("%s",*(obj->input))` then should print text after allocation and memcpy

Comment: It is normal because obj->input has not been initialized (with a valid address of a pointer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*(obj->input)` dereferences `input` before `input` points to valid memory, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), where manifesting with a segfault is common.  You first have to malloc memory for it before dereferencing.  You don't provide enough details about what you're trying to do, but something like:

```
struct shard *obj=malloc(sizeof(struct shard));
if (obj == NULL)
{
  // handle error how you want, and make a check like this for every malloc
  exit(-1);
}

obj->input = malloc(howManyCharPtrsYouWant * sizeof(*(object->input));
for (int i=0; i<howManyCharPtrsYouWant; i++)
{
  obj->input[i] = malloc(howManyCharsYouWant); // sizeof(char) is guaranteed to be 1, so no need to include it in `malloc`
}
```

See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70073561/3476780) for an explanation of `sizeof(*(object->input))` if you're unsure what's happening there.

`*(obj->input)=malloc(sizeof(char)+1);` only allocates space for 2 `char`s (`sizeof char == 1`, +1 == 2 total).  This is the smallest possible string you can have in C, one `char` followed by a `NUL` terminator.  So if you're trying to put more than 2 chars in that buffer, that's an overflow --> UB --> possible segfault.  If all you need is one `char`, better to bypass the `malloc` and simply use `char c;`, for example.

This is getting off topic, but the top two reasons you need dynamic memory allocation IMO are:

1. You won't know how much memory you'll need until *runtime*
2. You need "a lot" of memory (on your regular vanilla PC, I'd put this around 4+MB, but of course your mileage may vary depending on your needs and system).

SO has some good questions weighing the benefits of when to `malloc` or not, you can look them up.

If you know at compile time you'll need a max of 30 strings, only 30 chars long for example, then you can do something like

```
struct shard
{
    sem_t *semaphore_o;
    char input[30][30];
    // .. etc
};
```

and

```
struct shard obj; // you only need one of these, malloc makes little sense IMO
obj.semaphore_o = malloc(..); // this doesn't need to be a pointer either
strcpy(input[0], "hello there"); // fits in 29 chars plus NUL
strcpy(input[5], "I'm Jim");     // same
```

My preference is always to use automatic (stack) storage when possible, it's simpler because it relieves you of the burden of memory management.

Comment: thanks for answer please see the full code I posted in question update, In a thread its giving me warning  that `format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]
   58 |                 scanf("%s",((obj->input)));`

Comment: should I do `scanf("%s",(*(obj->input)));`

Comment: @user786 yes that's correct, the `"%s"` format specifier for `scanf` expects a `char*`, and that's what `*(obj->input)` is (`obj->input` is a `char**`). That means `"%s"` expects a `char` pointer to _at least two_ `char`s because you must leave room the `NUL` terminator. Just be wary of buffer overruns using pure `"%s"`, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306591/read-no-more-than-size-of-string-with-scanf) for a discussion about limiting input with `"%s"`.

Comment: is there a neat way to pass pointer to pointer as thread parameter. I do not want to have contrainer struct because want to allocate parameter in thread and use it in parent thread whats allocated in child thread? Doable?

Comment: @user786 That's an entirely different question, but sure, if I understand correctly. The threading library I use in C is pthreads. When you create a function for the thread to execute, it accepts a `void*`, which is a pointer to any data type. So if you want to pass a `char** myDblPtr;` for instance, it would be like `pthread_create( ..., &myDblPtr,..);`. Then in the function you need to cast the argument from `void*` back to your data type: `char** myDblPtr = (char**)threadArg;`. Look at pthread argument passing and ask a new question if still confused.

Comment: Sounds good will ask.

Comment: @user786 I told you wrong, that would be `pthread_create( ..., myDblPtr, ..);`, but yeah just ask a new question if you haven't already.